# Laravel. Keep variable in view during all routes

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-blade

I got pretty simple problem in laravel 4.2 but i can't solve it. I got included right-side-bar which must contain some content from my database table during all routes. I got mysql query on home page route and I pass variable to view:

```
$query....    
return View::make('home')->with('query', $query);
```

All I want is to send this vatiable to included view 'right-side-bar', but it has to recognize it during all routes. I tried nesting, sharing variable, but since routes change, my 'right-side-bar' view can't recognize variable $query. i would like to hear some suggestions how i can solve it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/views#view-composers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

**Using View Composers**

Keep in mind that when you are using view composers you should autoload your files/classes via composer.

The fast dirty way:

```
View::composer('your-view-name', function($view)
{
    $query = //your query code
    $view->with('query', $query);
});
```

or with multiple views:

```
View::composer(array('a-view','a-second-view'), function($view)
{
    $query = //your query code
    $view->with('query', $query);
});
```

The class based approach (**recommended**)

```
View::composer('my-view', 'MyViewComposerClass');
```

then create the class

```
class MyViewComposerClass{

    public function compose($view)
    {
        $query = //your query code
        $view->with('query', query );
    }

}
```

**Using the Base Controller**

Well an easy fix for what you want is to do something like this in your BaseController inside the constructor.

**BaseController.php**

```
public function __construct(){
        $query = //your query code
        View::share('query', $query);
}
```

And then make your other controllers(which obviously extend the BaseController)
to construct the parent controller in their constructors like this

**Other Controller that extends BaseController.php**

```
public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();

}
```

Then access the variable like you always do.

Hope this helps..

More about view composers :

Laravel 4.2: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses#view-composers

Laravel 5.1: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/views#view-composers

Comment: Clear and effective. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, in time you will get the hang of it :)

Comment: There is also the alternative of putting the code in [`App::before`](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/lifecycle#application-events) to be able to use this with route closures as well as controllers.

Comment: Also there's no need for defining the constructor on child classes just to call `parent::__construct();`, because that is done automatically when instantiating the object.

Comment: I wouldn’t suggest this and instead use a view controller like @lukasgeiter suggests, because now you have the overhead of having to call `parent::__construct()` any time you want to define a unique constructor in a controller. I’d also suggest caching the results of the query if this is being ran on _every_ request.

Comment: Yes I know view composers is the proper way, just wanted to give a simple explanation. Anyway I updated my answer and now includes view composers.