# returning data using laravel middleware

Tags: php, laravel

i'm trying to retrieve the navigation bar data from the database using middleware class so i can access it anywhere within the application
the data coming fine but the class printing the data as ajax response instead of passing it as an array
when i tried to navigate any route within the application it's printing out the data and die and not showing the correct view

```
 <?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use App\Navigation;
use App\PrimaryNavigation ;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
class NavigationMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $mainNavi = Navigation::with('PrimaryNavigation')->get() ;
        $subNavi = PrimaryNavigation::with('SubNavigation')->get() ;
        $navigation = [
            'main' => $mainNavi,
            'sub' =>$subNavi
        ];
        return Response($navigation);

    }
}
```

the middleware class registered within the kernel class

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\NavigationMiddleware::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    ];
```

Answer (score 3):

using middleware for doing that is not a good idea ,
 use view composers or ...    ,
see [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29078435/laravel-keep-variable-in-view-during-all-routes) too